# How do I export a snapshot using docker?

Tags: node, docker, snapshots

I did it below:

$ ./mainnet.sh shell

$ /usr/local/bin/tezos-node snapshot export BL8K1e24CHsqnMPzdyPcSDQpPh2Vr8TNbPcg4Et3cEHgvXx3H14.full

```
tezos-node: internal error, uncaught exception:
        (Failure "No such file or directory")
        Raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 2998, characters 20-29
        Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 26, characters 8-18
        Called from file "src/bin_node/node_snapshot_command.ml", line 70, characters 10-26
        Called from file "cmdliner_term.ml", line 25, characters 19-24
        Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 25, characters 27-34
        Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 116, characters 32-39
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you successfully found a solution to this? I believe tezos/docker doesn't currently support this (even though technically you weren't using docker and mainnet.sh to do the export).

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the data directory of your container using `--data-dir` argument:

`tezos-node snapshot export --block BMEH5XAWK4Z1Ds632VVyu9PjW2SKW27Mts4reL8fJCUQVFfgJu7 BMEH5XAWK4Z1Ds632VVyu9PjW2SKW27Mts4reL8fJCUQVFfgJu7.full --data-dir /var/run/tezos/node/data`

You can use `docker inspect` to find it, look for the Cmd entry in the output, e.g.:

`docker container inspect tz-node
...
            "Cmd": [
                "tezos-node",
                "run",
                "--history",
                "full",
                "--data-dir",
                "/var/run/tezos/node/data",
                "--net-addr",
                ":9732",
                "--rpc-addr",
                ":8732"
            ],
...`