# Error on export snapshot from docker?

Tags: docker, snapshots

The answer here doesn't work ([How do I export a snapshot using docker?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1329/how-do-i-export-a-snapshot-using-docker/1550#1550)) I first tried `sudo tezos-node snapshot export datadisk2/snapshot/sept252019.full` but I received the error:

`tezos-node: internal error, uncaught exception:
            (Failure "No such file or directory")
            Raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 2998, characters 20-29
            Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 26, characters 8-18
            Called from file "src/bin_node/node_snapshot_command.ml", line 70, characters 10-26
            Called from file "cmdliner_term.ml", line 25, characters 19-24
            Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 26, characters 27-34
            Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 117, characters 32-39`

I tried looking at docker inspect:
`docker container inspect alphanet_node_1` but the cmd doesn't have more than:

`"Cmd": [
    "tezos-node",
    "--net-addr",
    ":9732"
],`

I then tried `sudo tezos-node snapshot export datadisk2/snapshot/sept252019.full --data-dir /var/run/tezos/node` but received the error:

`tezos-node: Error:
              Expected to find data directory version file at '/var/run/tezos/node/version.json',  but the file does not exist.`

I then searched for the `version.json` with `sudo find / -name "version.json"` and got `/var/lib/docker/volumes/alphanet_node_data/_data/data/version.json`. I added this data-dir: `sudo tezos-node snapshot export datadisk2/snapshot/sept252019.full --data-dir /var/lib/docker/volumes/alphanet_node_data/_data/data` but I received the error:

`tezos-node: internal error, uncaught exception:
            (Failure "No such file or directory")
            Raised at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 2998, characters 20-29
            Called from file "src/unix/lwt_main.ml", line 26, characters 8-18
            Called from file "src/bin_node/node_snapshot_command.ml", line 70, characters 10-26
            Called from file "cmdliner_term.ml", line 25, characters 19-24
            Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 26, characters 27-34
            Called from file "cmdliner.ml", line 117, characters 32-39`

Any idea how to export the snapshot? Thanks for your help

Comment: The directory `datadisk2/snapshot` exists. I am using alphanet.

Comment: What is the network that you are using? (mainnet, alphanet, ...).